# Login form submit fails without throwing error

Tags: python, html, selenium

Just realized that a login form isn't being submitted despite not throwing an error:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver_path = "path to chromedriver.exe"
url_login = "https://www.findacode.com/signin.html"
username = 'jd@mailinator.com'
password = 'm%$)-Y95*^.1Gin+' #know it's not best practice to share passwords, but this is a trial account and credentials are necessary to appreciate the problem

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path, chrome_options=options)

driver.get(url_login)
form = driver.find_element_by_name('login')
form.find_element_by_name('id').send_keys(username)
form.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys(password)
form.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Sign In']").submit()
```

No error at this point, but login is unsuccessful:

`driver.title` is "Sign In - FindACode.com" but should be "Find-A-Code - ICD 10 Codes, CPT Codes, HCPCS Codes, ICD 9 Codes - Onlne Encoder - Medical Billing and Coding" and the rest of the page source confirms an unsuccessful sign on

I tried an explicit wait after calling .submit():

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
wait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "history"))) # history is an element in post login landing page but not in the pre login page
```

But I receive a timeout error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<input>", line 29, in <module>
File "...\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

I tried another explicit wait after calling .submit()

```
title = "Find-A-Code - ICD 10 Codes, CPT Codes, HCPCS Codes, ICD 9 Codes - Onlne Encoder - Medical Billing and Coding"    
wait(driver, 10).until(EC.title_is(title))
```

And I receive another timeout error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<input>", line 30, in <module>
File "...\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Per this [post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/43964324/login-is-not-working-in-selenium-webdriver-3-4-0-version), I also try a wait before calling send_keys(password) in case the password field is becoming stale

```
wait.until(EC.staleness_of((By.NAME, "password")))
```

But I can't seem to get the syntax right and the documentation isn't helpful:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<input>", line 26, in <module>
TypeError: until() missing 1 required positional argument: 'method'
```

Any pointers are much appreciated.

Comment: Provide html or url

Comment: It's in the post: `https://www.findacode.com/signin.html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use css locators below:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('form[name=login] input[name=id]').send_keys(username)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('form[name=login] input[name=password]').send_keys(password)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('form[name=login] input[type="submit"]').click()
```

Comment: That worked after I edited (by adding 'by' before 'css'). I updated your answer too. Please explain why this approach works over what I was doing? The explanation might be useful for my end goal.

Comment: Your problem was in submit xpath locator. When you search child element with xpath like element.find_element_by_xpath you have to add . in front of your selector. In your case “.//input”.